# Draw Image to Canvas with Color

Tags: dart, flutter

I use `canvas.drawImageRect` to draw an image to a canvas.

The image itself is just white with transparency, but I want it to have another color. I tried creating a Paint with the color set to yellow but that didn't made the image appear yellow.

I guess there is a way to do this, can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a Paint and add a [ColorFilter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter-class.html).

ColorFilter.mode(Color color, BlendMode blendMode)
Creates a color filter that applies the blend mode given as the second argument. The source color is the one given as the first argument, and the destination color is the one from the layer being composited.

I think you want srcATop BlendMode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I played around a bit with the ColorFilter and got it working the way I want using the srcATop BlendMode! Now my image is yellow. Would you minde changing destOut to srcATop in your answer? Then I can accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Corrected the blend mode.